# declared Variable turned "Undefined" dont know how?

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables, nestjs

I have this Config.ts file that contains some basic numbers
when initializing app it can read values from variables but later I cant read this variables because of "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initLevrage')
at getTimeName (\config.ts:38:22)"
please Help

```
import { log } from 'console';
import { ITimeFrameTypes } from '../tbBot/bot.interface';

export class Configs {
  private initMargin = 1;
  private initLevrage = [
    100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 15, 13, 11, 10, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3,
  ];
  private timeFrames: ITimeFrameTypes[] = [
    '1m',
    '5m',
    '15m',
    '1h',
    '4h',
    '1d',
    '1M',
  ];
  checkFrameType(name: ITimeFrameTypes) {
    let t: string = name;
    if (name == '1M') {
      t = '1mo';
    }
    return t;
  }
  getMarginInit() {
    return this.initMargin;
  }
  setMarginInit(n: number) {
    this.initMargin = n;
  }
  getLevrages() {
    return this.initLevrage.map(x=>x);
  }
  getTimes() {
    return this.timeFrames.map(x=>x);
  }
  getTimeName(i: number) {
    log( typeof this.initLevrage);
    let t = this.timeFrames[i];
    return this.checkFrameType(t);
  }
  getTimeIndex(name: ITimeFrameTypes) {
    let t = this.timeFrames.indexOf(name);
    return t;
  }
}
```

it Logs iniLevrage Values fist but cant find it later

I have tried to move these vaiables out of class scope , then assign them to variables but no diffrence

Comment: How are you trying to use this class? I instantiated and used, and it worked: `const config = new Configs();`
`config.getTimeName(0);`
`config.getLevrages();`

Comment: I my problem is in the class I get Error for Undefined at 
`log( typeof this.initLevrage);
    let t = this.timeFrames[i];`

Comment: and yes I have initialized the Config with `new` in other classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is likely with how you're invoking your methods – check out [this TS playground I set up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

I think for a quick fix, you can change your methods from

```
  getTimeName(i: number) {
    log( typeof this.initLevrage);
    let t = this.timeFrames[i];
    return this.checkFrameType(t);
  }
```

to

```
  getTimeName = (i: number) => {
    log( typeof this.initLevrage);
    let t = this.timeFrames[i];
    return this.checkFrameType(t);
  }
```

The latter *anonymous function* will let you access `this` from any context you'd like

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
I was calling the function like this:
`let frame = this.config.getTimeName;` then calling frame : `frame(i)`
deleting frame and using `this.config.getTimeName(i)` , the problem was Gone.

thanks

Comment: but dont know why it gave me the problem

Comment: I was not using `let frame = this.config.getTimeName`

Comment: changing it to `let frame =()=> this.config.getTimeName()` was the right way